# what is the mistake of this code?

Tags: android

why is raw folder in code have a red line although i have this folder !!!! ?

[image]

what is the wrong ?

```
package com.example.second;
```

public class omar extends Activity {

```
MediaPlayer song;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle omar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(omar);
    setContentView(R.layout.omar);

    song = MediaPlayer.create(omar.this, R.raw.one);
    song.start();


    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(5000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent open = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                startActivity(open);
            }

        }
    };
    timer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();

    song.release();
    finish();
}


}
```

and what is the last method mean ?

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();

    song.release();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: okay thanks all,but i want any one to explain to me the last method :)

Answer (score 4):

You have `res/layout/raw`, while it should be `res/raw` I believe.

Comment: You'll probably want to rebuild.

Comment: Rebuilding will cause Eclipse (among other things) to trigger the Android tool to recreate the `R` file, which will now include all resources inside `res/raw`.

Answer (score 3):

`raw` should be outside from the `layout` folder and inside `res`
Please prefer this.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Answer (score 0):

You have `res/layout/raw`. It's not right. It's `res/raw`

Also follow the link given to you by rup35h.

Answer (score 0):

When the activity is being paused it is a good strategy to release the resources used by the MediaPlayer object.That's what release() does here.

finish() just finishes the activity

Check these out

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release()

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()